# MS Outlook Distribution List Count

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone show me how to see how many contacts are in a Distribution List?

At the moment the Distribution List just shows the name and email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I've found is to Export / Save As your Distribution List / Contact Group as a text file, and use a text editor such as Notepad++ to see the line count:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, this site [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/countdlmembers.htm) has a macro you can download and run on a distribution list to return the count.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free [Email Address Report](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookReportAddresses) available that shows the total number of addresses. Just select the required distribution lists and make sure to set the "Expand address groups" option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of email addresses in an Exchange distribution list you can use PowerShell.

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
$distributionlist = (Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive "*Name of Distribution List*")
$distributionlist.Count
```

If you want to count the number of email addresses in an Outlook distribution list Jonno's answer will do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello Jonno, the macro is now saying there is only 1 member when there are over 150 members. I have tried re-adding the macro, but it still keeps on saying 1 member

Comment: Hello Jonno, the macro is now saying there is only 1 member when there are over 150 members. I have tried re-adding the macro, but it still keeps on saying 1 member